# Convergence of diffeomorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $(\Sigma, g)$ be a compact $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold without boundary. Let $F_i$ be a sequence of diffeomorphisms of $\Sigma$ and $u_i$ be a sequence of positive scalar functions.

Suppose $\gamma_i := u_i^2 F_i^* g$ converges to a Riemannian metric $\gamma$ on $\Sigma$ smoothly. Is there a way to find a subsequence of $F_i$ (possibly after composing with conformal maps of $(\Sigma, g)$) that converges to a diffeomorphism?

If not, consider the simpler case where $u_i \equiv 1$. Namely, if $\gamma_i = F_i^* g$ converges to $\gamma$ smoothly, can we say anything about the convergence of $F_i$ (possibly after composing with isometries of $g$)?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The case when $u_i=1$ should follow from Ebin-Palais slice theorem: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-74/issue-5/On-the-space-of-Riemannian-metrics/bams/1183529951.full. The $Diff(M)$ orbit of $g$ is a closed subset homeomorphic to the quotient of $Diff(M)$ by the isometry group of $g$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! It does take care of the case when $u_i=1$. Separately, I would also like to know if there is some version of this Ebin-Palais slice theorem for compact manifolds *with* boundary.

Comment: There is a paper "The manifold of Riemannian metrics on a compact manifold with boundary", by Maxim-Răileanu. Another source is Hamanaka's "Decompositions of the space of Riemannian metrics on a compact manifold with boundary".

Comment: Thank you very much!